# Automapper multiple porperties only if they are not null in on property

Tags: c#, automapper

I have to return CallerAddress property like a string.Concat from multiple properties unless they are not null. So far, i've tried this, but is not working. After mapping my CallerAddress is equal to "Str. SomeStreetName". I`ve looked up in my db and i have values on the other colums. So, how can i make this to work?

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ClientRecordingsDao,ClientRecording>()
    .ForMember(x => x.CallerAddress,
                        b =>
                            b.MapFrom(
                                x => x.CallerStreet != String.Empty
                                    ? "Str." + x.CallerStreet 
                                    : String.Empty +
                                      x.CallerStreetNumber != String.Empty
                                        ? " Nr."
                                        : String.Empty + x.CallerStreetNumber +
                                          x.CallerBuilding != String.Empty
                                            ? " Bl."
                                            : String.Empty + x.CallerBuilding +
                                              x.CallerApartment != String.Empty
                                                ? " Ap."
                                                : String.Empty + x.CallerApartment))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It applies `+` opertator to wrong place. Wrap each of your comparing in `()`:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ClientRecordingsDao,ClientRecording>()
     .ForMember(x => x.CallerAddress, b => b.MapFrom(
         x => (x.CallerStreet != String.Empty ? "Str." + x.CallerStreet : String.Empty) +
             (x.CallerStreetNumber != String.Empty ? " Nr." + x.CallerStreetNumber : String.Empty) +
             (x.CallerBuilding != String.Empty ? " Bl." + x.CallerBuilding : String.Empty) +
             (x.CallerApartment != String.Empty ? " Ap." + x.CallerApartment : String.Empty)));
```

Your code maps to this:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<ClientRecordingsDao,ClientRecording>()
     .ForMember(x => x.CallerAddress, b => b.MapFrom(
         x => x.CallerStreet != String.Empty ? "Str." + x.CallerStreet :
         (String.Empty + x.CallerStreetNumber != String.Empty ? " Nr." + x.CallerStreetNumber :
         (String.Empty + x.CallerBuilding != String.Empty ? " Bl." + x.CallerBuilding : 
         (String.Empty + x.CallerApartment != String.Empty ? " Ap." +  x.CallerApartment : String.Empty)))));
```